# How to transfer a state array to props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

So I have 2 React files, an App.js and a category.js. When I transfer my array to category.js, it shows a huge blob of text instead of splitting it into different array buttons. I tried searching but I don't understand how to do it. Can someone explain it?

here is the class App

```
class App extends React.Component {
Object.keys(data.categories).forEach((category,index) => {
    arr.push(data.categories[index].name);
})

render() {
return (
<div>
    <Categories 
      categoryName = { this.state.categoryName }
    />
</div>
```

and here is the categories using props

```
const Categories = props => (
<div>
    <br /> 
    { props.categoryName && <button> { props.categoryName } </button>}
</div>
);
```

Comment: Hi @Kevin, can you please provide sample Data Object which you are trying to loop over.

Comment: Hi @JigneshRaval I'm using an API call so it's in a JSON format with something like {categories: {1,2,3,4,5.....} } as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map over your `categoryName` array

```
const Categories = props => (
   <div>
      <br /> 
      { props.categoryName &&
        props.categoryName.map(name => <button>{name}</button>)}
   </div>
   );
```

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the simple solution on mapping it!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your categories are an array of objects in your component state,  `map` over the state categories and return a `Category` component with each iteration of the array.

```js
function Category({ categoryName }) {
  return (<button>{categoryName}</button>);
}


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { categories: [ { categoryName: 'Bob', type: 'string' },  { categoryName: 'Trevor', type: 'number' }] };
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         {this.state.categories.map(category => {
           return <Category categoryName={category.categoryName} />
         })}
       </div>
     )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```